# Plot which should show two functions shows nothing

Tags: plotting

This is my first time using *Mathematica* and my plot is not showing up.
I have set the variables and functions independently.

```
Function1[x_] := Sqrt[(m*(V - x)*a^2)/(2*h^2)]
Function2[x_] := Sqrt[(m*x*a^2)/(2*h^2)] Tan[Sqrt[(m*x*a^2)/(2*h^2)]]
Plot[{Function1, Function2}, {x, 0, 1.3*^-18}]
```

The functions do not show up on the plot.

[image: Function1 & Function2 Plot]

Comment: First, you cannot plot a function where `m`, `V`, ... is not a number. So make sure you gave them values. Secondly, your plot command is wrong. You want `Plot[{Function1[x],Function2[x]},{x,0,1.3*^-18}]`. Thirdly, be careful when you use so small plot ranges because `Plot` could choke upon this. Just a warning.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I set the variables ex: m = 9.109*^-31

Comment: What command should I use if want to plot small ranges?

Comment: @user34343 Scale the whole thing up

Comment: thanks! I added the [x] after function and the functions show up on the plot now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[{Function1[x], Function2[x]}, {x, 0, 1.3*^-18}]
```

Corrected code -- I needed to tell `Plot` that the two functions are functions of `x`.

Comment: Bbgodfrey and m_goldberg: this is in effect the correct answer. The poster of the question forgot to give the functions an argument and this answer provides the correct solution. It is not this answer that should be closed bu the question ( as a simple mistake).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries. You're right, but it was expressed so poorly, it read like a correction to the question. I have edited it to make the solution more obvious.